# List creation on installation NOT activation for a feature?

Tags: list, feature

I have a Sharepoint feature that includes a settings list template, which is read by other features. The list must have a particular name for the whole thing to work, so ideally I would rather have a list created instead of a list template.

However I need the list to be permanent as the list can be updated manually to add more settings. Am I wrong in my understand that if I used this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476062.aspx every time it's activated the list is a new one that can't be saved? If so how do I go about just creating the list on installation instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No if you use List Definition with List Instance element, you can set the list instance property `Deployment Conflict Resolution=None` and your list instance will not be deployed (or not replaced with a new one).

The list instance will only be created if it doesn't already exists. If it exists nothing will happen, nor the items will be touched.